# Is there a way to store a sequence of bytes/binary data in an MPS concept instance?

Tags: mps

MPS has the possibility of storing Java `string`s in concept properties. Is there a builtin possibility to store an equivalent of a `byte[]` into a concept property?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the behavior aspect of your concept, you can do a downcast to a lower semantic level by doing typing this/ (so type "this" somewhere in one of your behavior methods where you want to store the byte array and then / and then press ctrl+space to choose the downcast to lower semantic level operation, see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD20182/SModel+language for the downcast documentation). Then you can call putUserObject and getUserObject to associate any java object with your concept.
I am not sure if there is a ByteArray class in java to box your byte array, but you can always make a wrapper class if boxing doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try.